# Kusto query to extract a value from nested column

Tags: kql, azure-log-analytics

I want to extract the file name from Entities column from sentinel logs in log analytics

Using the below query i am able to extract particular column Entities

```
SecurityAlert | where ProviderName == "MDATP" | where AlertType == "WindowsDefenderAv"| project Entities
```

But I want to fetch highlighted text ( File name) from nested rows, can anyone let me know what filters do i add to get specific value ?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FHnVa.png)

Comment: can you please add sample input json data here in text format?

Comment: Here it is ----- [{"$id":"2","Directory":"/tmp","Name":"eicar.com.txt","FileHashes":[{"$id":"3","Algorithm":"SHA1","Value":"3395856ce81f2b7382dee72602f798b642f14140","Type":"filehash"},{"$id":"4","Algorithm":"SHA256","Value":"275a021bbfb6489e54d471899f7db9d1663fc695ec2fe2a2c4538aabf651fd0f","Type":"filehash"}],"Type":"file"}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

something like this (using `mv-expand` or `mv-apply`) can get you started:

```
SecurityAlert
| where ProviderName == "MDATP"
| where AlertType == "WindowsDefenderAv"
| project Entities
| mv-expand Entities
| project Entities.Name
```

see documentation:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/scalar-data-types/dynamic
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/mvexpandoperator
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/mv-applyoperator

Answer (score 0):

Using `bag_unpack()` plugin of kusto you can covert properties of a dynamic object as a column. It will get invoke with `evaluate` operator. Please [refer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/bag-unpackplugin).

Below is sample query

```
print dynamicData = dynamic(
{"$id": "2", 
"Directory": "/tmp", 
"Name": "eicar.com.txt", 
"FileHashes": [
{"$id": "3", "Algorithm": "SHA1", "Value": "3395856ce81f2b7382dee72602f798b642f14140", "Type": "filehash"}, 
{"$id": "4", "Algorithm": "SHA256", "Value": "275a021bbfb6489e54d471899f7db9d1663fc695ec2fe2a2c4538aabf651fd0f", "Type": "filehash"}
],
"Type": "file"})
| evaluate bag_unpack(dynamicData)
| project Name
```

**Result**

[image]